# $a,b: \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables. And let's have $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. What is the distribution of $r$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

$a,b: \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables. And let's have $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. What is the distribution of $r$?

So, I have two random variables, distributed normally, what is the distribution of $r$ given as such. This turned out to be quite a difficult problem at the university, and we haven't the knowledge or experience with dealing with this particular problem, so thought to ask, how such a problem is to be solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDF of the Euclidean norm of $M$ Normal distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235089/pdf-of-the-euclidean-norm-of-m-normal-distributions), see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155829/euclidian-norm-of-gaussian-vectors

Comment: See also [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution).